# Exception in login application

Tags: hibernate, exception, struts2, java-6

I am  new to Struts and hibernate. For understanding it i tried doing a login application. I use Struts 2, Hibernate 3.2.5, Java 6, Tomcat 6, in netbeans IDE 7.1.2. I am getting an exception like

**Exception**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

root cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hibernateutilities.HibernateUtil
```

**Server log**

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter
```

I am getting this exception when executing

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
```

If anyone want more details please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding with the error, You have *asm* version that is incompatible with your Hibernate version.

It's hard to tell at this time the exact matching version so i believe my best bet will be to take help of maven and let maven do this in correct way for me,

other way is to look [hibernate-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) for dependencies and its version

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the HibernateUtil class from Hibernate tutorial? Anyway, check what versions of asm you're bundling with your web-application as well as if there is one deployed directly in Tomcat - there may be a conflict and an incompatible version gets loaded (AFAIR Hibernate had some 'detached' JAR-s that solved this problem).